# How to add method id in metamask

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have deployed smart contract using remix IDE, launched with Injected Web3 on Ropsten test network. I could call `BuyTokens` function within solidity IDE successfully, but when tried to buy tokens with metamask from other address transaction get reverted. I can see the difference between those operations on ropsten.etherscan explorer - the difference is in `Input Data` field.
Metamask transaction has value 0x and transaction via remix is:

```
Function: buyTokens() ***

MethodID: 0xd0febe4c
```

Code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract Token {
    // Track how many tokens are owned by each address.
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    // Modify this section
    string public name = "DemoCoin";
    string public symbol = "DC";
    uint8 public decimals = 8;
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000000 * (uint256(10) ** decimals);
    address public owner;
    //uint scaler = 10e18; // == 1 ETH in wei
    //uint public coinPrice = 20; //initial price => 20 cents
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    constructor()  {
        // Initially assign all tokens to the contract's creator.
        owner = msg.sender;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }
    
    // Might be executed automaticlly
    // https://blog.chronologic.network/schedule-your-transaction-now-using-mycrypto-and-myetherwallet-17b48166b412
    
    // function changeCoinPrice() public {
    //     uint newCoinPrice;
    //     require(msg.sender == address(0));
    //     coinPrice = newCoinPrice;
        
    // }
    
    function buyTokens() public payable {
        // msg.value in wei so 1ETH = 10e18
        // lets set 0.20 cents for 1 token
        uint paidAmount;
        
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= paidAmount);
        require(balanceOf[owner] >= value);
        uint tokens;
        tokens = value/10e14;
        balanceOf[owner] -= tokens;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += tokens;
        emit Transfer(owner, msg.sender, tokens);
    }
    
    function msgSenderBalancce() public view returns (uint) {
        return balanceOf[msg.sender];
    }
    
    function withDrawEth() public view {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        
        
    }

}
```

Why these methods are called diffrently? And how to add method id in metamask? Or am I missing something and this should be handled in other way?

Comment: Try to search [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

MetaMask has a very basic UI. It only allows transfers of ETH and standardized tokens, but it doesn't show any buttons to call other contract functions. It also doesn't allow creating any custom buttons in their UI.

**You'll need to set the `data` field of the transaction to `0xd0febe4c` (which effectively executes the `buyTokens()` function).**

But - they also don't allow specifying the `data` field value manually in the UI, so you'll need to preset it using the Ethereum provider API.

1. Your web app [connects](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/accessing-accounts.html) to the user's MetaMask acccount. It opens a MetaMask window and the user needs to manually confirm the connect.
2. The web app [sends a request](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-request-args) to MetaMask specifying the transaction with `data` field value.
3. The user confirms the transaction (which now includes the `data` field value `0xd0febe4c`) in their MetaMask UI.